# app sends an email based on inputs - How can I preview the emai?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I'll start by saying, I'm new to Oracle Apex.

I have an application prepared that can take in user inputs. On choosing the 'create' button these are saved to a table row AND an email is fired.

The email is built in HTML as a process. It takes in the page items displays them in a particular order in the html and sends to chosen recipients.

Can anyone suggest how a preview of the email could be viewed? Or point me to a tutorial that explains/demonstrates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **DisplayOnly** item to display *p_body_html* if you are using APEX_MAIL.SEND.
Remember to **Set Escape special characters** on it to No.

Comment: I struggled with this for a while. In the end I created the preview page on a separate page. And on my first page used a dynamic action for each page element with Execute PL/SQL :

Comment: Sorry my comment sent before it was finished. Execute PL/SQL:  begin
null;
end; This enabled the saving of the change temporarily so that it could be read in preview mode. the info eventually gets saved when create is selected.  thank you very much for your feedback DanBoc.